# Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found ',' at line 22 column 298

Tags: querylocator

Based on the requirement i have written a batch and schedule class for an email notification to be sent before 90 days.
I have used the below  query in the code ,where i used to get an email notification mail.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator('Select  id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c ,ownerId,Owner.Email, Account.Owner.Email  FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds');
```

Now we had few conditions to be added in the code ,

```
Condition is when the "Renewal_Status__c" is equal to 'Pushed Forward To Next Quarter','In Pipe' AND when "Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c" is not equal to'Renewed','Renewal lost’.
```

The System throws an Error as :

> Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found ',' at line 22
>   column 298     When i use this query

```
Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c, Owner.Email, Owner.Manager.Email ,Account.Owner.Email,Account.Owner.Manager.Email  FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds AND Renewal_Status__c IN :('Pushed Forward To Next Quarter','In Pipe') AND Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c IN :('Renewed','Renewal lost’)]);
```

If i use in another way :

```
return Database.getQueryLocator('Select  id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c, Owner.Email, Owner.Manager.Email ,
                                   Account.Owner.Email,Account.Owner.Manager.Email  FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds
                                         AND Renewal_Status__c IN :(\'Pushed Forward To Next Quarter\', \'In Pipe\') 
                                         AND Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c IN :(\'Renewed\', \'Renewal lost\')');
```

the system throws another error as :

> line breaks not allowed in string literals at line 18 column -1

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Bit of a guess, but try adding values in `IN :('Pushed Forward To Next Quarter','In Pipe')` and `IN :('Renewed','Renewal lost’)` to Sets?

Comment: I guess that salesforce doesn't support multiline strings. I think you should do like:
String query = 'select Id' + <line break> ' FROM Account' + <line break> + ...

Comment: `'Renewed','Renewal lost’` the , after lost as superscript is typo in first method?

Comment: first should be `Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c, Owner.Email, Owner.Manager.Email ,Account.Owner.Email,Account.Owner.Manager.Email  FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN setContractIds AND Renewal_Status__c IN ('Pushed Forward To Next Quarter','In Pipe') AND Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c IN ('Renewed','Renewal lost’)]);` without colon

Comment: @Poet,@Kurunve,@ Vigneshwaran G,@sfdcweb:Thanks for your response.When i use Query return Database.getQueryLocator('Select  id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c ,ownerId,Owner.Email, Account.Owner.Email  FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds');The i get the email notification but when i give the condition and use the query as stated above ,i dont get any email notification.Any Suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

In first method, `:` is not required since you are not using any bind variables.

```
Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c, Owner.Email, Owner.Manager.Email ,Account.Owner.Email,Account.Owner.Manager.Email  FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds AND Renewal_Status__c IN ('Pushed Forward To Next Quarter','In Pipe') AND Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c IN ('Renewed','Renewal lost')]);
```

In second method, querylocator doesn't allow multi line string as input. So it should be single line and here also `:` is not required.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator('Select  id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c, Owner.Email, Owner.Manager.Email , Account.Owner.Email,Account.Owner.Manager.Email  FROM  Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds AND Renewal_Status__c IN (\'Pushed Forward To Next Quarter\', \'In Pipe\') AND Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c IN (\'Renewed\', \'Renewal lost\')');
```

Hope it helps.